# Internal Differences Between File deleted from GUI and CLI

Tags: command-line, files, delete, inotify

I am using inotify system call for watching one of my file for all the events (delete,modify etc).

But When I deleted file from GUI, no notification was fired.
Whereas when I deleted file from CLI then [:attrib] event on that file was notified.

Is this issue in inotify call or I am missing anything.

Comment: When you deleted the file in the GUI was it moved to the trash and was the result the same when you deleted from the command line? Food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting from the GUI, the file gets *moved* to the trash (inode update), so no modification/deletion, so no notification!

When `rm file` from the cli, it gets deleted, so you get a notification...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "1" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Fabby is right, when we delete from the GUI it will be moved to trash.

But If we do <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> it's detected by `inotify`.

Even If you are copying some file/directory to the directory under-monitor or moving them out of it, these events are not captured.

If you want to capture these events, then you can subscribe for IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO events in `inotify`.